# Area of a Surface of Revolution over Y-Axis

Tags: area

I need to set up an integral for the area of a surface rotated over both the x-axis and the y-axis. Given $y = e^{-x^2}$ over the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

I'm having difficulty, however, finding this equation when rotating over the $y$-axis, particularly in terms of the limits of integration. Here's what I have so far.

The operative formula is $\int_a^b 2 \pi x \ ds$ with $ds = \sqrt{1 + \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2} \ dx$. Based on $y = e^{x^2}$, we can get 
\begin{align*}
& f(x) = e^{x^2} \Rightarrow f'(x) -2x e^{-x^2} \Rightarrow \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2 = \Big(-2x e^{-x^2}\Big)^2 = 4x^2 e^{-2x^2} \\
\end{align*}
which means that $ds$ is 
\begin{align*}
ds = \sqrt{1 + \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 e^{-2x^2}}
\end{align*}
Putting together our integral then gives us 
\begin{align*}
S = \int_{-1}^1 2 \pi x \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 e^{-2x^2}}
\end{align*}
This answer, however, is incorrect; the correct limits of integration are from $0$ to $1$, and I cannot understand why this is the case. If anyone has any insight on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the graph of $y = e^{-x^2}$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ is a 
mirror image (over the $y$ axis) 
of the graph of $y = e^{-x^2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1.$

So if you just take the right-hand half of the curve,
$y = e^{-x^2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$
and rotate it by $\pi$ radians around the $y$ axis, you end up with the
left-hand half of the curve.
In the meantime you have swept over half of the desired surface of rotation.
If you then continue to rotate another $\pi$ radians, you return to the original position of the right-hand half,
while sweeping through the other half of the surface of rotation.

If you take *both* sides of the curve $y = e^{-x^2}$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$
and rotate them through $2\pi$ radians around the $y$ axis,
they will each sweep through parts of the surface that the other side of the curve swept through (or will sweep through) $\pi$ radians earlier or $\pi$ radians later. You'll end up with twice the correct answer because you counted every part of the surface twice.

To fix this, you *could* take the entire curve and rotate it only $\pi$ radians, which would sweep through the entire surface exactly once.
You would then evaluate
$$
S = \int_{-1}^1 \pi x \sqrt{1 + 4x^2 e^{-2x^2}} dx.
$$
(Notice the factor of $2$ that occurs in the formula in the question but not in the formula above.)
But I think most people think it's simpler to take just one half of the curve and rotate it through a full revolution of $2\pi$ radians so that the calculation is more like the calculation for other surfaces of rotation.
In particular, notice that $x$ is the *radius* of the circle traced by a point $(x,y)$ when rotating that point around the $y$ axis, and integrating over negative values of the radius is a bit weird.